# How to resize base64 image using gm

Tags: node.js, npm

I can't seem to make it work to resize. How can I resize base64 image using gm?

I have the following code:

```
 var regexBase64ContentType     = /^data:image\/\w+;base64,/;
 var buffer = new Buffer(imgData.replace(regexBase64ContentType, ""),'base64');

    gm(buffer, "img.png")
        .resize(height, width)
        .toBuffer('PNG', function(err, buf){
            return buf;
        });
```

Comment: What is the error or incorrect result you are getting?